# Estilos Bootstrap

Tags: php, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo una app web a la cual quiero incorporarle bootstrap como asi tambien estilos personalizados.
El problema es que me toma los estilos predeterminados de bootstrap pero no los personalizados que aplico. 
Por ejemplo: 
en el index.php tengo un jumbotron, al cual quiero personalizar.

```
          <?php include('includes3/meta2.php'); ?>

            //Mas codigo
        <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container"><h1>QUIENES SOMOS</h1></div>
        <img src="img3/imgHeadAcercaDe.jpg">
      </div>
```

Y en el .css

```
/*JUMBOTRON*/

.jumbotron {
background-color: transparent;
position: relative;
padding-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
}

.jumbotron img {
width: 100%;
}

.jumbotron h1{
position: absolute;
bottom: 25%;
color: #FFF;
text-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #18367c;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: 400;
}
```

Sin embargo no me toma esos estilos ya que no se ve así y cuando veo mediante F12 me muestra que el estilo del jumbotron lo toma de bootstrap.min.css y la tipografía, etc inherited from body.

En el meta2.php:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="es">
     <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8>"
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--Stylesheets-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css3/estilos.css"/>
      <!--Bootstrap-->
     <script 
      src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
```

Como podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Si, me referia a que el index es .php y que la hoja de estilos está añadida mediante un include, según he leído quizas a veces por eso no toma los estilos.

Comment: estas importando los estilos 2 veces, y en el segundo caso en el href te falta el http en la url

Comment: Como dos veces? en el primero importo el min.js y en el segundo el min.css

Comment: No, importas 2 veces lo mismo.  *href="css3/estilos.css"* y *href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'*.

Comment: Nop, estilos.css es mi hoja de estilos personalizada.

Comment: Bien, pensé que habías renombrado la de boostrap. El problema que veo es que a tu *href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'* le falta el https. deberia quedar asi *href='https: //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'* . No te olvides sacar el espacio que agregue yo porque no me deja poner el link completo.

Comment: Gracias Lucas! ya lo cambie!!

Comment: Perfecto, si te funciona no te olvides de marcar mi repuesta con el "tick" así le sirve a otros que tengan el mismo problema en un futuro. Un placer @Maria Laura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

los estilos amigo, se deben aplicar en `HTML`, después de eso deberías:

1. poner tu hoja de estilos personalizada en segunda posición
2. luego invocar a `bootstrap`, p*ara que esta última no te sobre escriba tus estilos*

**MUESTRA DE CÓDIGO**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="MiHojaEstilos.css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

> los estilos al ser en cascada, se ejecutarán primero los del enlace a
>   boostrap y posteriormente los de `MiHojaEstilos.css` para de este modo
>   mantener los estilos que tu mismo generaste

Comment: Alfredo noto que eres nuevo en el sitio. Tu respuesta es correcta pero le darías mas peso y relevancia si colocas un ejemplo con código funcional. De esta forma el dueño de la pregunta se guía mejor y los otros usuarios de la comunidad puntuan tu valioso aporte con mayor frecuencia. Un Saludo!

Comment: entendido gracias por las observaciones

Comment: De nada bro!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Tal como dice la [documentacion de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) tienes que añadir el siguiente codigo en tu etiqueta ***head***. No debes olvidarte de importar los archivos de JavaScript!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Si ya tienes en alguna carpeta de tu proyecto el archivo bootstrap.min.css o bootstrap.css seria algo asi:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Tu codigo deberia quedar asi:

```
<head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Acá es donde tienes mal apuntada la dirección, te falta el http -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
```